# encrypt sensitive information

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, couchdb

I want to build a web site which at the backend uses node.js express.js and couchdb which will store some sensitive information. I want to know how is it possible to encrypt sensitive information and store it in couchdb. What is the most secure way to encrypt the data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. almost all languages support cryptography either directly or indirectly.

NodeJS provides a crypto module;
The crypto module provides cryptographic functionality that includes a set of wrappers for OpenSSL's hash, HMAC, cipher, decipher, sign, and verify function

for reference visit: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html